# What is the hadith regarding minor signs of Qyamah by Ibn Masud?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, end-times

I came by a video which tells about a hadith where Ibn Masud asks the prophet (phub) about the signs of Qyamah and then our Prophet (pbuh) states many signs.  I found it very amazing.  But I couldn't find the Hadith or even it source.  Can anyone give me the hadith along with its source?

The video was this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCMgwwDkFxE

Partial transcript:

> Ibn Masood said "I said to the Prophet"
>   "Does the hour have a knowledge that you can know it by?"
>   He said "Yes, Oh Ibn Masood".
>   And Muslims have to know these signs
>   so they recognise them when they see them.
>   And there are many signs
>   One of the signs
>   Children become filled with rage
>   Rain becomes burning or acidic. Acid rain.
>   You'll see evil people spreading widely
>   "Oh Ibn Masood from the signs and conditions of the Hour is that
>   people will trust treacherous people
>   and they will consider trustworthy people treacherous
>   The truthful one will be called a liar
>   and the one telling a lie will be called truthful.
>   These are signs.
>   This to me is one of the clear Prophetic miracles of the Prophet.
>   He said ...
>   That the dishes will be communicating continuously
>   and the Prophet used the very word
>   And people will sever their family ties.
>   In other words people will stay home and watch television
>   on satellite dish, and they won't go visit their neighbors

Comment: I found this link that says the hadith was cited by At-Tabaraani in Al-Awsat and Al-Kabeer, and its chain of narration includes Sayf ibn Miskeen, who is a weak reporter.

http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=343078

Answer (score 3):

Well after listening to the first seconds of this video i did a search for the first 3 signs described and found this "[hadith](https://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=747&pid=373019&hid=2062)" (Arabic) in a book called "tratyb al-Amaly al-Khomaysiyah (or al-Khamysiyah)" of ash-Shajary ترتيب الأمالي الخميسية للشجري  (an apparently [Zaydi](http://books.islam-db.com/author/%D9%8A%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%89_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A) scholar).

---

A quick overlook about some rawy's who might be an indication of weakness for this hadith:

Well the rawy Abu Obaydah abdu-l-Warith Ibrahim al-Askary  أَبُو عُبَيْدَةَ عَبْدُ الْوَارِثِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ الْعَسْكَرِيِّ is an unkonwn

And the one he's referencing: Sayf ibn Miskyn al-Aswaary  سَيْفُ بْنُ مِسْكِينٍ الْأَسْوَارِيُّ is a known fabricator!

And Mobarak ibn Fadalah  مُبَارَكُ بْنُ فَضَالَةَ has been accused to do tadlees (in cases)

---

But apparently the speaker even added some signs not mentioned in that book, some of them known from other ahadith!

And Allah knows best!

Comment: @Shadman: please consider accepting this answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

Alright. The YouTube video is an excerpt from a lengthy lecture delivered in Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia in 2014 by American Sunni Islamic scholar Sheikh Hamza Yusuf, President of Zaytuna College and member of the Commission on Unalienable Rights, a human-rights advisory panel to the US President. 
Now the exact reference of this lengthy Hadith is in Al Mu'jam Al Kabir (10/228), written by Imam Sulaiman ibn Ahmad At-Tabarani. The Hadith goes as follows:

يَا ابْنَ مَسْعُودٍ ، إِنَّ مِنْ أَعْلَامِ السَّاعَةِ وَأَشْرَاطِهَا أَنْ تُوَاصَلَ الْأَطْبَاقُ ، وَأَنْ تُقَاطَعَ الْأَرْحَامُ

Translation (could vary): O Ibn Mas’ood, from among the signs of Qiyamah is that dishes will communicate continuously and people will sever their family ties